# How to hide div with Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to be able to hide a div with Vue, with as little impact on performance as possible, since it's a couple of divs on the website that will be treated this way. How do I do this?

*Hide div > Display it when clicking on another div:*
([Example (without Vue)](https://jsfiddle.net/3v65gcg7/))

**With Vue** (not working)

**html**

```
<div id="app" v-on:click="seen = !seen" class="control">
    <p>click app</p>
</div>

<div v-if="seen" id="hide">
<p>hide me </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
new Vue({
    el:'#hide',
    data:{
        seen: false
    }
})
```

Comment: Vue can't change things outside your app root

Comment: @Ferrybig You are right... I forgot to include the important part...

Comment: Vue cannot toggle the show/hide status of the root element, as vue needs to have at least 1 root element

Comment: @Ferrybig Ok, I get it, it's only possible to hide the elements within a div, but not the div itself.

Comment: No, you did not get it.

Comment: Well, technically you can access elements outside the root element... https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As @Ferrybig stated, Vue only has control over the element it's bound to and all of those child elements.  Your `hide` element is outside the element bound to Vue (`app`) so Vue cannot change it.

With a slight change, your code works fine:

```js
new Vue({
el:'#wrapper',
data:{
    seen: true
}
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="app" v-on:click="seen = !seen" class="control">
      <p>click app</p>
  </div>
        
  <div v-if="seen" id="hide">
      <p>hide me </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution is abit dangerous. Because with "v-if" the div element does not being  rendering in the DOM. May be v-show is better.

Answer (score 15):

I recommend either use "v-show" or ":class" for hiding component efficiently. I've had some weird situations, the v-show may cause the ag-grid component into bad data table however no problem when using  ":class".

The template code could be:

```
<div v-show="seen" id="hide">
   <p>hide me </p>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div :class="{ hide: !seen }" id="hide">
   <p>hide me </p>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.hide {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Is that .hide style defined by vue.js or do I have to do that in my css?

Comment: @BitTickler .hide is a css defined in your css file or if you want to only work locally, you can define in the specific .vue file.

Answer (score 9):

You can use v-if-else or v-show, they work in different ways. v-if, v-else will attach/detach your HTML element to its root element. On the other hand, v-show will work with style="display:none;",

**example: v-if, v-else**

```
<body>
    <div id = 'app'>
        <button @click="show = !show">Click</button>
        <p v-if="show"> 
            v-if value of show is: {{show}}
        </p>
        <p v-else> 
            v-else value of show is: {{show}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data: function(){
                return{
                    show: true
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**example v-show**

```
<body>
    <div id = 'app'>
        <button @click="show = !show">Click</button>
        <p v-show="show"> 
            v-show works with style="display:none;"
        </p>

    </div>
    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data: function(){
                return{
                    show: true
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

An vue instance has its own scope.Only in its scope, it can control the element.You need to focus on the element which be mounted.And one instance, one root element.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Multiple instances are okay and if you have, say 2 instances, you can invoke setters from one instance to the other: `methods... toggleViewX: function () { viewX.$data.isShow = !viewX.$data.isShow } ...}`

Comment: While Vue's $data property allows direct access to the data within a component instance, it is not widely recommended for extensive use in practical development. Using the $data property to access data can make the code harder to maintain and introduce potential issues.
You may use $refs, lift the state, or invoke the setter using some functions that are passed to the children. These methods align better with Vue's design principles and help improve code maintainability and extensibility. @BitTickler

Comment: And how do you do that if you have multiple app instances, which was the topic of my comment above? The same topic arises, btw, if the completion function of an e.g.. `XMLHttpRequest` is executed in a null environment.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I saw your comment above, this is actually what `v-show` does, it will do it by directly modifying the display property of the element's inline style to `none` to not display the element. Also, please check out the Vue's documentation.