# Change style inside function two times

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, dom, styles

I've a vue application. My code:

```
console.log('1')
document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = 'visible'
this.encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(this.em), this.pd).toString();
console.log(this.encrypted)
document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = 'hidden'
console.log('2')
```

I tried it with classbind, async await, v-if directives etc. the console.logs are in order so the consol.log('2') is logged at last, and waiting for this.encrypted to be resolved.

What i want is  that the #loader is styled during the function, before the execution of this.encrypted and afterwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide div with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578738/how-to-hide-div-with-vue-js)

Comment: No, cause i want to show AND hide after the function is done. It's overlay which should appear when data is processed.

Comment: oh, but it does - exactly in [this answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62229253/9078341)

Comment: Do you really need loader here? CryptoJS.AES.encrypt doesn't return a Promise, so it is done synchonously and you can't add await. Those style changes are not even applied.

Comment: I think i do, cause it takes a few seconds and if nothing is happening within these few seconds, the user will think that the app is  broken.